# Factorial(x) for x>170 using Rmpfr/gmp library

Tags: r, factorial

The problem that I would like to solve is the infinite sum over the following function:

[image]

For the sum I use an FTOL determination criterion. This whole term doesn't create any problems until `z` becomes very large. I expect the maximum value of `z` around 220. As you can see the first term has its max around Factorial(221) and therefore has to go around Factorial(500) until the determination criterion has been reached. After spotting this problem I didn't want to change the whole code (as it is only one small part) and tried to use `library('Rmpfr')` and `library('gmp')`. The problem is that I do not get what I want to. While multiplication normally works, subtraction fails for higher values:

This works

```
> factorialZ(22)-factorial(22)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 0
```

but this fails:

```
> factorialZ(50)-factorial(50)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 359073645150499628823711419759505502520867983196160
```

another way I tried:

```
> gamma(as(10,"mpfr"))-factorial(9)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
[1] 0

> gamma(as(40,"mpfr"))-factorial(39)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
[1] 1770811808798664813196481658880
```

There has to be something that I don't really understand. Does someone have a even better solution for the problem or can someone help me out with the issue above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you incorrectly understand the priorities in `factorialZ(x)-factorial(x)` .  The second term, `factorial(x)` is calculated **before** it's converted to a `bigz` to be combined with the first term.

You must create any integer outside the 2^64 (or whatever, depending on your machine) range using a `bigz` - compatible function.

Comment: Just to illustrate by example, this works (returns zero): `factorialZ(39) - factorial(as.bigz(39))`

Comment: I see, i was not aware of the fact that R calculates "that wrong" with "small" numbers like `factorial(27)`. Thanks for the explenation. 

Is it correct when I say that using `as(whatever,"mpfr")` is more accurate but more costly than the standard double precision? So I can actually use mpfr for accurate calculations and then convert the result into as.double when doing less demanding calculations? do you agree? thanks a lot for the quick answers

Comment: `factorialZ(39) - factorial(as.bigz(39))` are identical because they are both executing exactly the same code: `gamma.bigz(39 + 1)` is being called for both because of the method dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

50! is between 2^214 and 2^215 so the closest representable numbers are 2^(214-52) apart.  `factorial` in R is based on a Lanczos approximation whereas factorialZ is calculating it exactly.  The answers are within the machine precision:

```
> all.equal(as.numeric(factorialZ(50)), factorial(50))
[1] TRUE
```

The part that you're not understanding is floating point and it's limitations.  You're only getting ~15 digits of precision in floating point.  factorialZ(50) has a LOT more precision than that, so you shouldn't expect them to be the same.