# The Largest factorial number in R

Tags: r, precision

If I run the `factorial(1:200)`, the largest value is `7.257416e+306`, any value above that is `"Inf"`.

1. Does this means the largest value inside R programming is `7.257416e+306`.
   We can not calculate the value above `factorial(170)`?
2. But when I run the code ".Machine$double.xmax", the biggest value is `1.797693e+308`.

So, I am a bit confused, which one is the biggest value in R?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791496/r-factorialx-for-x170-using-rmpfr-gmp-library

Answer (score 4):

The largest number in base R has nothing to do with the factorial function. The likelihood that the largest number is going to coincide with a factorial is very small. The largest representable number differs depending on your computer. You can see it by running. `.Machine$double.xmax`. Everything above that is `Inf`.

You see `171*factorial(170)` is simply larger than your machine's `.Machine$double.xmax` even though `factorial(170)` is smaller.

If you want larger numbers in R consider the discussion [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r)

Comment: Thank you.  I understand your first part, but not quite get your second part. If the largest value in R is depending on your machine. The factorial(170) is clearly bigger than my ".Machine$double.xmax." Isn't it out of number range? and also if i want ot calculate the value e.g. factorial(200), how can i do it ?

Comment: ```factorial(170)``` is ```7.257416e+306``` which is cleary smaller than ```1.797693e+308```, that you say is your ```.Machine$double.xmax```. If you write ```factorial(170) < .Machine$double.xmax``` youll see that.

Comment: sorry, my bad the factorial(170) is smaller than 1.797693e+308. So if it is smaller, how can we calculate the factorial(180) or factorial(200)?

Comment: Just check out the post that I linked.